# Is there a way to differentiate in iOS mail notifications by account?

Tags: ios, mail.app, email, notifications

Specifically, the notification (both unlocked & locked screen) in iOS. I have setup two mail accounts (iCloud and another server). When I receive a new message, the notification shows the sender, subject and the first row of the message’s body.

Is it possible to show the account where the mail was received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible using the default Mail app. It only allows you to differentiate between VIPs and regular senders (by placing a ☆ next to VIPs).

If you want to differentiate which account received an email within a notification, you would need to use a separate app for one of your accounts. You will then get separate notification settings for that app, and a different notification icon as well.

Comment: Thank you, I am using the Inbox by Gmail app also, so I just wanted to use the default Mail app. Whereas it's not possible, i am closing this thread. Thanks again.